# Cloth multiple pins moving individually

Tags: cloth-simulation

I pinned the plane on four corners, that Vertex Group is the pin group in the cloth modifier.
Does anybody know how to move the corners individually and second how to unpin them individually?

Comment: You can animate meshes using shapekeys

Comment: Thank you. Yes I Tried that. Now I only need to unpin or drop one corner. Any idea?

Comment: Animate the the vertex  weight

Comment: ok thank you. I searched on that topic and found Vertex Weight Proximity and played around with it. Now I can achieve the effect I want. thanks a lot